# Problems with PHP basedir paths after Wordpress migration to new server

Tags: php, wordpress

Moved a Wordpress site to a new server, to avoid changing database entries I have recreated the original absolute path on this server, wich is:

```
/var/www/vhosts/trb-wine.com/httpdocs
```

This is not the default path on this distro, as is an Arch Linux and the default is `/srv/http`

So, I went ahead and added `/var/www:` to the basedir directive in php.ini, then accessed site and get this on the error log :

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/trb-wine.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/include_framework.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/trb-wine.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php on line 16" while reading response header from upstream
```

So there is a problem with the basedir PHP path, but I quite don't get how to solve it. I have tried adding the full path on the basedir directive but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "changing database entries"? WordPress doesn't care what directory it's in.

Comment: When you migrate a wordpress intall from site to site, you need to change the absolute path in your database in order to avoid malfunction, as plugins do have a record with the absolute path. In order to avoid touching the database, i wanted to recreate the absolute path of the old server to the new one. Just some mimutes ago i realized that those calls are actually not made based on the database absolute path and it is probably a filesystem related problem, as the site backup weigths more than the original. So it may actualy be that the files can't be found somehow. I will post result later.